# C++ type name as a literal string for error report in static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, types, static-assert

I am using this macro to make sure some types line up:

```
#define TYPE_EQ(t1, t2) static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value)
```

Bear with my contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TYPE_EQ(t1, t2) static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value)

class Fn1 {
 public:
    int operator()(const char s) {
        return s == 'a' ? 0 : 1;
    }
    typedef char Domain;
    typedef int Codomain;
};

class Fn2 {
 public:
    char operator()(const bool s) {
        return s ? 'a' : 'b';
    }
    typedef bool Domain;
    typedef char Codomain;
};

template<typename F1, typename F2>
class Compose {
 public:
    Compose () {
        TYPE_EQ(typename F1::Domain, typename F2::Codomain);
    }

    typedef typename F1::Codomain Codomain;
    typedef typename F2::Domain Domain;

    Codomain operator()(const Domain& x) {
        F1 f1;
        F2 f2;
        return f1(f2(x));
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Compose<Fn2, Fn1>()(true) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here I get simply `error: static_assert failed`, but I would like to know what the type mismatch is. For that I think I would need a string representation of the types at compile time so for example I could have:

```
#define TYPE_EQ(t1, t2) static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value, \
                                      type_str(t1) " != " type_str(t2))
```

Edit: I didn't think compilers would disaggree on this. I don't have gcc ATM but clang sais:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 test.cc -o test && ./test
test.cc:27:9: error: static_assert failed
        TYPE_EQ(typename F1::Domain, typename F2::Codomain);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:3:25: note: expanded from macro 'TYPE_EQ'
#define TYPE_EQ(t1, t2) static_assert(std::is_same<t1, t2>::value)
                        ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:41:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'Compose<Fn2, Fn1>::Compose'
      requested here
    std::cout << Compose<Fn2, Fn1>()(true) << std::endl;
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

To clarify the real problem is much more complex so I want the *final* types, ie `int` and `boo`, not typenames.

Comment: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/65zxHCvsf0KR5B3z) and Gcc give some addtional message, .e.g. "error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same<typename Fn2::Domain, typename Fn1::Codomain>::value'". Isn't it enough?

Comment: I think the details of the static assertion itself are detailed enough (the types *are* in the static code source after all), no?

Comment: To hopefully answer both of you, in my applicationthere are multiple levels of indirection for the typenames (think for example nested `Compose`) so it is usually very hard to hunt down the final types.

Comment: @fakedrake so in other words, you want a mechanism to resolve [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to their most basic constituents. Not aware of such thing; let's see what others suggest.

Comment: Yes, and also get me a string representation of that so I can compose a meaningful error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical way to retrieve type for debugging is to use incomplete type:

```
template <typename> struct Debug;

Debug<Fn1::Domain> d;
```

Produces error similar to:

> error: aggregate '`Debug<char> d`' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
>        `Debug<Fn1::Domain> d;`

Comment: I am accepting this because it's very useful and I didn't know it but is there a way to go all the way down to a concrete type (in this case `char` rather than `Fn1::Domain`)?